# Self-signed certificate for code signing not showing up in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, code-signing, keychain

I'm developing a small app on Xcode 4.2 in Lion to learn the basics of Mac development.

I've got a directory picker controller class as an NSOpenSavePanelDelegate, implementing the `- panel:validateURL:error:` method, where I'm attempting to make sure that the directory that the user chooses contains files of a certain type that the app supports.

I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844383/nssavepanel-and-the-sandbox) here on SO, discovering that the delegate methods don't have access to the file system in sandboxed applications. This would be a problem for the aforementioned case.

Eager to learn more about this, I decided to try sandboxing the app to see what happens. I enabled entitlements and sandboxing for the build target in Xcode and then created a self-signed certificate for code signing in Keychain Access, following [this tutorial](http://www.smartapps.co/2011/02/tutorial-code-signing-in-xcode-4/). The certificate lives inside my login keychain.

The problem is, the freshly created certificate doesn't appear under the Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Identity dropdown. The only thing that is there is "3rd Party Mac Developer Application", but the build fails with a code signing issue if that is selected.

Any ideas how I can get it to show up?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. After Quitting and restarting Xcode, my own certificate showed up.